# Use the string between <a href="...>STRING</a> as filename?

Tags: wget

I was wondering if it ist possible to make wget use the string between the -tag as a filename.

There are hundreds of documents to be downloaded (all legally) from an internal Website, but the website kind of sucks. Using wget without any parameters results in filenames like `"c0f506da-0184-d621-7ab2-c0300875bda3,11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111.pdf"`. Using wget with – content-disposition gets a proper filename (like `"AB1999.pdf"`), but the filenames used within the website aren't any good. **The proper names would be the ones SHOWN in the website**: the string between `<a href=...>STRING</a>` would be the perfect Name.

**Is there a way to make wget use this ahref-string as Filename?** I read the help/documentation, but I just couldn't find it.

If not: is there another way to achieve this (using ahref-string as filename in a download/downloadmanager)?

Comment: Here: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523809/how-can-i-extract-a-tags-attribute-value-from-an-html-file" should give you the ability to extract a value between a HTML tag of your choice. You'll be best to `curl` the webpage to a local file, then write a script to loop the file/build an array etc. and then you can wget to your heart's content to get your files.

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured a way myself, but I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I made the browser display the sourcecode of the website and copied/imported it into Excel/Notepad++, which I then used to transform the lines (search/replace).

So I transformed

```
<a href="../../med/c5b/c5b704b3-4afd-7851-2e58-2f5241a133e2,11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111.pdf" target="_blank" title="A proper Filename - Opens a new window">A proper Filename</a>&nbsp;<br>
```

into

```
wget -O "A proper filename.pdf" "http://mywebsite//med/475/47570cd0-f77c-af51-93ca-0763041a133e,11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111.pdf"
```

Not perfect, but works.

Best regards and have a nice day,
Alex